# Why Highchart area color is black?

Tags: highcharts

I use Highchart with `areaspline` type and my problem is the area is got be blacked or gray based on `fillOpacity` in `plotOptionsp` property. I use this in different syntax type but the result is same.

For example :

```
plotOptions: {
     area: {
         fillOpacity: 0.5,
    },
}
```

or :

```
plotOptions: {
     series: {
         fillOpacity: 0.5,
    },
}
```

You can see the screenshot of result:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
chart: {
    type: 'areaspline'
},
title: {
    text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 150,
    y: 100,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
        'Sunday'
    ],
    plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
        from: 4.5,
        to: 6.5,
        color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
    }]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit units'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    valueSuffix: ' units'
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
}]
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you please post live example of your issue, like jsFiddle? When I have tested your code everything is working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/k018u1fn/1/

Comment: Unfortunately when I create live example every thing is ok.

Comment: You may try to manually set fillColor: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.fillColor

Comment: Is it possible to customize it in css?

Comment: It is possible to use highcharts-area class: http://jsfiddle.net/7negf4au/

Comment: I didn't use `css` or manually  `fillColor` at all. Another thing that I understand is tooltip background is black too.

Comment: are you using styled version of highcharts or standard HC version (which link are you loading to your web page)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148225/discussion-between-mohammad-and-grzegorz-blachlinski).